# Absolute value in integrating factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

So the problem is:

> $(3+t) x' + x = sin(t)$,  $x(0) = 0$

The integrating factor is $(3+t)$, but shouldn't it be $|3+t|$? As e raised to the the integral of $1/(3+t)$ is $|3+t|$ not $(3+t)$? I suspect it has something to do with the initial condition, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: the integral is $ln(\frac{|3+t|}{\lambda})$

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You get for the homogeneous equation, after exponentiation,
$$
|x|=C·|3+t|
$$
The only variant of sign combinations that is continuously differentiable everywhere is $x=C·(3+t)$.

Of course, one could also immediately see that the left side is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}((3+t)·x(t)).
$$